# Monitoring a directory for changes in OSX without fsevent

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4, fsevents

Is there an alternative to fsevent or some kind of wrapper for it?

I'm trying to monitor a specific folder for changes to files with a certain extension.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Observe a File or Folder in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386743/observe-a-file-or-folder-in-objective-c)

Comment: @Rob Keniger: Not a duplicate of that question, since that one doesn't exclude FSEvents and, in fact, FSEvents (which you suggested on that question) is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [UKKQueue](http://zathras.de/programming/cocoa/UKKQueue.zip/), which is a nice wrapper for kernel queue event monitoring - the alternative mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @Peter Heh. Thanks for the edit. I started writing, got sidetracked, then came back to it without proof reading. :-)

Comment: Looks like VDKQueue is an updated version of UKKQueue (which is 8 years old). https://github.com/bdkjones/VDKQueue

Answer (score 1):

These days you can use GCD to monitor folders without any other dependencies:

```
import Foundation

@objc public class DirectoryWatcher : NSObject {
    override public init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    deinit {
        stop()
    }
    
    public typealias Callback = (_ directoryWatcher: DirectoryWatcher) -> Void
    
    @objc public convenience init(withPath path: String, callback: @escaping Callback) {
        self.init()
        if !watch(path: path, callback: callback) {
            assert(false)
        }
    }
    
    private var dirFD : Int32 = -1 {
        didSet {
            if oldValue != -1 {
                close(oldValue)
            }
        }
    }
    private var dispatchSource : DispatchSourceFileSystemObject?
    
    @objc public func watch(path: String, callback: @escaping Callback) -> Bool {
        // Open the directory
        dirFD = open(path, O_EVTONLY)
        if dirFD < 0 {
            return false
        }
        
        // Create and configure a DispatchSource to monitor it
        let dispatchSource = DispatchSource.makeFileSystemObjectSource(fileDescriptor: dirFD, eventMask: .write, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        dispatchSource.setEventHandler {[unowned self] in
            callback(self)
        }
        dispatchSource.setCancelHandler {[unowned self] in
            self.dirFD = -1
        }
        self.dispatchSource = dispatchSource

        // Start monitoring
        dispatchSource.resume()
        
        // Success
        return true
    }

    @objc public func stop() {
        // Leave if not monitoring
        guard let dispatchSource = dispatchSource else {
            return
        }
        
        // Don't listen to more events
        dispatchSource.setEventHandler(handler: nil)
        
        // Cancel the source (this will also close the directory)
        dispatchSource.cancel()
        self.dispatchSource = nil
    }
}
```

Use it like Apple's DirectoryWatcher example, something like this:

```
let directoryWatcher = DirectoryWatcher(withPath: "/path/to/the/folder/you/want/to/monitor/", callback: {
    print("the folder changed")
})
```

Destroying the object will stop watching, or you can stop it explicitly

```
directoryWatcher.stop()
```

It should be compatible with Objective C they way it's written (untested). Using it would be like this:

```
DirectoryWatcher *directoryWatcher = [DirectoryWatcher.alloc initWithPath: @"/path/to/the/folder/you/want/to/monitor/" callback: ^(DirectoryWatcher *directoryWatcher) {
    NSLog(@"the folder changed")
}];
```

Stopping it is similar

```
[directoryWatcher stop];
```