# NSFileManager watch directory

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsfilemanager

How would you monitor a directory with `NSFileManager`?

I would like to able to detect when a file is deleted/added in my documents directory while my app is running.

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209811/monitoring-a-directory-for-changes-in-osx-without-fsevent

Comment: possible duplicate of [Observe a File or Folder in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386743/observe-a-file-or-folder-in-objective-c)

Comment: this question is tagged as iPhone. And none of those linked answers works in iOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look *Kernel Queues: An Alternative to File System Events* in Apple documentation. 
There is an **example for iOS** in AVPlayerDemo (look `DirectoryWatcher` class).

Also, check [Directory Monitor](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=2312) blog post.

Comment: Apple has added official sample on DirectoryWatcher https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Apple moved the sample, here's the new link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo

Answer (score 12):

Here's my own version of DirectoryWatcher written in Swift using GCD instead of Mach and using a closure instead of a delegate

```
import Foundation

@objc public class DirectoryWatcher : NSObject {
    override public init() {
        super.init()
    }

    deinit {
        stop()
    }

    public typealias Callback = (_ directoryWatcher: DirectoryWatcher) -> Void

    @objc public convenience init(withPath path: String, callback: @escaping Callback) {
        self.init()
        if !watch(path: path, callback: callback) {
            assert(false)
        }
    }

    private var dirFD : Int32 = -1 {
        didSet {
            if oldValue != -1 {
                close(oldValue)
            }
        }
    }
    private var dispatchSource : DispatchSourceFileSystemObject?

    @objc public func watch(path: String, callback: @escaping Callback) -> Bool {
        // Open the directory
        dirFD = open(path, O_EVTONLY)
        if dirFD < 0 {
            return false
        }

        // Create and configure a DispatchSource to monitor it
        let dispatchSource = DispatchSource.makeFileSystemObjectSource(fileDescriptor: dirFD, eventMask: .write, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        dispatchSource.setEventHandler {[unowned self] in
            callback(self)
        }
        dispatchSource.setCancelHandler {[unowned self] in
            self.dirFD = -1
        }
        self.dispatchSource = dispatchSource

        // Start monitoring
        dispatchSource.resume()

        // Success
        return true
    }

    @objc public func stop() {
        // Leave if not monitoring
        guard let dispatchSource = dispatchSource else {
            return
        }

        // Don't listen to more events
        dispatchSource.setEventHandler(handler: nil)

        // Cancel the source (this will also close the directory)
        dispatchSource.cancel()
        self.dispatchSource = nil
    }
}
```

Use it like Apple's DirectoryWatcher example, something like this:

```
let directoryWatcher = DirectoryWatcher(withPath: "/path/to/the/folder/you/want/to/monitor/", callback: {
    print("the folder changed")
})
```

Destroying the object will stop watching, or you can stop it explicitly

```
directoryWatcher.stop()
```

It should be compatible with Objective C they way it's written (untested). Using it would be like this:

```
DirectoryWatcher *directoryWatcher = [DirectoryWatcher.alloc initWithPath: @"/path/to/the/folder/you/want/to/monitor/" callback: ^(DirectoryWatcher *directoryWatcher) {
    NSLog(@"the folder changed")
}];
```

Stopping it is similar

```
[directoryWatcher stop];
```

Comment: Should seriously consider making this the primary answer, as the original answer has not aged well. Although the doc reference in the original is correct, the code referred to in the original is so old, it has all but disappeared (as per the comments). And the referred blog post actual utilizes direct run loop manipulation (a bit foreign in the age of Swift).

Comment: Nice solution, but does not track sub folders

Comment: @kamyFC That's true, but I don't know of any that do (Apple's DirectoryWatcher doesn't, does it?)

Comment: Does this work on Linux?