# How to use DispatchQueue to wait for a file to be created in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async, dispatch-queue

I'm developing an app that needs to wait for files to be created in the disk in order to continue.

After obtaining the array of paths from the json file, I need the app to:

- Show a progress bar
- Wait for each file to be created in order
- Update the progress bar after each file is created

The problem is that when I use a .sync queue, the UI never shows and is waiting for all the files to be created, and if I use a .async queue, the UI shows and the for loop runs all the queues concurrently

```
do {
    let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: jsonFilePathURL)
    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    let steps = try jsonDecoder.decode(Response.self, from: jsonData)
    
    let totalStepsCount = steps.steps.count
    
    initializeProgressBar(stepsCount:totalStepsCount)
    
    // Run a loop for each file to watch
    for step in steps.steps {
        waitForFileToBeCreated(path: step.Path) 
    }
```

I use this to wait for each file to be created.

```
func waitForFileToBeCreated(path:String) {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
        
        while !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path) {
                // Wait for the file to be created
                Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1)
            }
        
        group.leave()
        
    }
    group.wait()
    
}
```

Comment: *Who* does create the file?

Comment: It could be bom files or log files created with another app or a script. One of the uses would be a script that runs a workflow, I could use the app to present the user with the steps being run and completed.

Comment: Waiting is bad and sleeping on a thread is worse. Better than `DispatchGroup` is `DispatchSource` and a file descriptor to monitor a directory. It **notifies** when a file appears (for example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867991/nsfilemanager-watch-directory).

Comment: That was one of my options, but I want to WAIT until a specific file is created, then move on to the next and so on until the array is complete.