# How to get folder changes notifications(folder watcher) in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, filesystemwatcher, fsevents, kqueue

I am new to Cocoa Application development. I want my application to be notified when any file under a given directory is modified(folder watcher). Modified means deleted, added, content of file is changed. I tried using FSEvents also with using NSWorkspace's notification center or delegate messages as in UKKQueue at http://www.zathras.de/angelweb/sourcecode.htm#UKKQueue. My application got notification when any file under directory is modified. But the problem is that its not giving name or path of specific file which is modified. It gives path of directory but not path of specific file.

Any idea how can I watch folder for modification in specific file??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Observe a File or Folder in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386743/observe-a-file-or-folder-in-objective-c)

Comment: kqueues will monitor changes in individual files but you must set up the monitoring for each file yourself. `UKKQueue` doesn't work too well for this out of the box as it only allows a single delegate.

Comment: Is there any other method by which I can watch folder as my requirement??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to write code to keep track of the contents of the folder and then whenever you receive an `FSEvent` notification that the folder contents have changed, you need to compare your stored information about the folder contents with the actual, current contents.

This could be something as simple as a mutable array ivar named something like `folderContents`, which contains a set of file attributes dictionaries. You could use the dictionary returned from the `-attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` method of `NSFileManager` or a subset of it.

All you'd need to do when you receive a folder notification is iterate through the stored dictionaries and check to see whether any files have been added, removed or modified. The `NSFileManager` attributes dictionary contains all the info you need to do this.

You'd then need to update your stored information about the folder with the updated information.

Comment: Can you provide me example code for this because as I told I'm new to Cocoa Application development.

Answer (score 5):

NSMetadataQuery works well for watching folders:

```
- (void)setupWatchedFolder {
    NSString *watchedFolder = @"/path/to/foo";

    NSMetadataQuery *query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
    [query setSearchScopes:@[watchedFolder]];
    [query setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE '*.*'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey]];

    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(queryFoundStuff:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:query];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(queryFoundStuff:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification object:query];

    [query startQuery];
}

- (void)queryFoundStuff:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSMetadataQuery *query = self.metadataQuery;
    [query disableUpdates];

    NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.metadataQuery.resultCount];

    for (NSUInteger i=0; i<self.metadataQuery.resultCount; i++) {
        [results addObject:[[self.metadataQuery resultAtIndex:i] valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemPathKey]];
    }

    // do something with you search results
    // self.results = results;

    [query enableUpdates];
}
```

Comment: It seems a nice idea but I can't make it work. QueryFoundStuff is never called.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I've updated the query predicate to match what I'm using in my app

Comment: Is it possible to use NSMetadataQuery + NSNotificationCenter to get **only** the action (file renamed, file moved, file added) with the full path name without the need of iterating over the whole watched folder and to map against the last folder snapshot? I try to implement a DirectoryWatcher  to inform other code parts when a file was deleted or added or renamed inside a watched folder. I like to send the action+filePath. Could you give me a hint? Thanks