# Detecting removal and addition of files/folders cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, file, detection

I would like to get an idea of how to detect if a folder or file was removed or added to a specified folder listed in my code, there is not much to elaborate on.

Comment: I'd love to answer this myself, [but this question has already been asked here on StackOverflow before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386743/observe-a-file-or-folder-in-objective-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [File System Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

> The file system events API provides a way for your application to ask
>   for notification when the contents of a directory hierarchy are
>   modified.

Take a look at [Using the File System Events API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH4-SW4)

> The File System Events API consists of several distinct groups of
>   functions. You can obtain general information about volumes and events
>   by using functions that begin with [FSEvents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/Reference/reference.html).